# Platform for online group classes

Tags: discussion, online-resources

I'd like to attend some group classes online to improve my speaking. My goal is to take a test like IELTS or TOEFL. Do you guys know any platform that offers online group classes with a well structured level program?

Comment: ELU is not a language learning site so it is not as likely for people here to know of such things. But [ell.se] and [languagelearning.se] are very much into learning English or other languages...you may have better luck there. By the way, [italki](italki.com) and [hello talk](https://www.hellotalk.com/) are both conversation with real people (I have no idea about whether they do things special for IELTS or TOEFL).

Comment: Thank you for the tips

Comment: I used to practice English speaking on the [Free4Talk](https://www.free4talk.com).   
There's also [Elsa Speaking](https://elsaspeak.com/en) to practice pronunciation.